# Mule Cluster error: Invalid cluster configuration: Node failed to start

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb, mule-cluster

I will explain a little about the architecture that we have the problem, we have a cluster in AWS with 2 servers, one is the primary and the other is the replica in on premise version 4.3 (both servers running in AWS) with JVM 11.0.12, but I don't know why for days the secondary instance failed and the Mule runtime has appeared as in "disconnected" state, I decided to enter the server to check and I found in the mule logs the following message:
A Fatal error has occurred while the server was running:

```
*
* Invalid cluster configuration: Node failed to start!                         *
* (java.lang.RuntimeException)                    

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.SelectorOptimizer (file:hazelcast-3.12.jar) to field sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.SelectorOptimizer
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
DEBUG 2022-12-07 18:43:31,509 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.HazelcastClusterManager: Node failed to start!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:138) ~[hazelcast-3.12.jar:3.12]


INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: Mule cluster setup properties >>>
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: Cluster id: 12611154
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: Cluster node id: 2
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: Discovery SPI is not enabled.
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: Reading backup data: false
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: Multicast to discover cluster nodes disabled
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: TCP/IP to discover cluster nodes enabled
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: TCP/IP time to connect 20 seconds
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: TCP/IP discovery members:
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger:  - 10.0.3.193
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger:  - 10.0.3.84
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: Using port 5701 for inbound connections
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: Inbound request port autoincrement is enabled
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: Using random port for outobund connections
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: No network interface restriction. Using all available interfaces
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,694 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: Message backup count: 1
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,710 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: Quorum enabled: false
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,710 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: Quorum size: 0
INFO  2022-12-07 16:07:44,710 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.config.ClusterConfigLogger: Mule cluster setup properties <<<
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.SelectorOptimizer (file:/C:/MuleRuntime-Dev/mule/lib/opt/hazelcast-3.12.jar) to field sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.SelectorOptimizer
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
DEBUG 2022-12-07 16:12:49,744 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.cluster.internal.HazelcastClusterManager: Node failed to start!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:138) ~[hazelcast-3.12.jar:3.12]
```

and when we try to reset the server or the instance manually the server show the same message I don't know what happen because nobody changed anything.

Could you please help me if you had been the same error or know how to solve.

Comment: What version of JDK are you using in each node? One node is running in AWS and the other is on prem? Both have the same Mule version and patch level?

Comment: both servers running in AWS with internet connection and the ports are open with JVM 11.0.12

Comment: Is that the complete mule_ee.log before the runtime stops? Looks like there are lines missing.

Comment: The warning is not relevant. It is fixed in Mule 4.4.0. It happens when running in previous Mule 4.x releases with JDK 11.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by a connectivity issue between the nodes or some change in the network that prevents a node to reach the other or changed the access (like change of IPs, ports closed, etc). Another possibility is a change in Hazelcast libraries in only one of the nodes but you said you didn't make changes and you should not change those libraries unless provided in a Mule patch.

Review the logs for other clustering errors. Don't pay attention to debug level logs. Try to identify what the problem was and fix the networking in your AWS VPC.

The warning `An illegal reflective access operation has occurred` should not relevant to this error. It is fixed in Mule 4.4.0. It happens when running in previous Mule 4.x releases with JDK 11.